# C#, SQL Server : rounding

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I need to round up the decimal type in C# and T-SQL. Rounding should take into account all digits in the number.

For instance:

rounding to tenths:

```
0.44 -> 0.4
0.45 -> 0.5
```

rounding to integer:

```
0.44 -> 0.0
0.45 -> 1.0
```

Standard methods are not suitable:

```
-- T-SQL
print round(0.44, 1) ---> 0.40 Nice
print round(0.45, 1) ---> 0.50 Nice
print round(0.44, 0) ---> 0.00 Nice
print round(0.45, 0) ---> 0.00 Bad (need 1.00)

// C#
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.44m, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); //-> 0.40 Nice
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.45m, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); //-> 0.50 Nice
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.44m, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); //-> 0.00 Nice
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(0.45m, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); //-> 0.00 Bad (need 1.00)
```

Earlier, I believed that `round` (T-SQL) and `Math.Round` (C#) worked as I needed. But no. Strange, but there is practically no information on the subject on the net.

**Summary:** a value of 0.45 (and similar ones, for example 0.44445) should be rounded up step by step for each digit and lead to 1:

```
0.45 -> 0.50 -> 1.00.
```

The integer part of the rounded number is not always 0. Maybe 1.2.3 ... 100.

Are there any standard C# and T-SQL functions with this behavior?

What is the best way to implement this?

---

**Update**

**Why is this needed?**
My customer works with a lot of indicators that need to be rounded. Each indicator displays the success of users in their work. The described approach will improve these indicators. The improvement will benefit both the customer and users. Therefore, this rounding option is considered.

I agree with the view that rounding is mathematically incorrect. I was led to an error by the fact that both values of 0.45 and rounded 0.5 appear in the program in an explicit form. C# and T-SQL functions work correctly.

Comment: Why would `0.45` round to `1`? It's less than `0.5` so it rounds to `0`. That's correct.

Comment: why are you expecting`round(0.45, 0)` with result of `1` ? `0.45` is less than `0.50`

Comment: So would the number `0.444444444444445` round to `1` as well? But, `0.4444444344445` would round to `0`? *Why*? That isnt' how rounding works.

Comment: As well as clarifying what you want, I'd strongly recommend asking two separate questions - one for C# and one for SQL.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for your recommendations. I provided an explanation. Thanks to StackOverflow users for their opinions and answers. It's enough. If the problem develops, I will divide the question into two branches.

Comment: Math.Round will work like you want but you want to use the overload that takes in a rounding mode parameter

Answer (score 2):

You can fool it with a loop:

```
double n = ...
int precision = 5;
while (precision >= 0) n = Math.Round(n, precision--);

return (int)n;
```

Comment: Good answer!  The initial value of precision (where you have 5) should be greater than or equal to the number of significant digits after the decimal point.  The final value of precision (where you have 0) should be the desired final precision (i.e. 0 or 1 in the example in the question).

Comment: Thanks, maybe this option is right for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to *multiply* by `9 / 8` factor before rounding:

```
  round(0.45, 1)         -> round(0.45 * 9 / 8, 1)         -- T-SQL

  Math.Round(0.45m, ...) -> Math.Round(0.45m * 9 / 8, ...) // C#
```

**C# Code**

```
  Func<double, int, double> round = (value, digits) =>
     Math.Round(value * 9 / 8, digits, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

**Demo:**

```
  double[] tests = new double[] {
    0.44,
    0.45,
  };

  string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test} => {round(test, 1)}")
    .Concat(tests
    .Select(test => $"{test} => {round(test, 0)}")));

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
0.44 => 0.5
0.45 => 0.5
0.44 => 0
0.45 => 1
```

Comment: Sorry, the condition described is not clear. The integer part of the rounded number is not always 0. Maybe 1.2.3 ... 100. Thanks for the answer